# Expresión regular JS para quitar parámetros

Tags: javascript, parametros

Hola buen día intento limpiar una URL sólo para quedarme con el nombre producto pero sin los parámetros de campaña (fbclid, gclid, UTMs) los cuales son opcionales ya que no todo el tráfico viene de campañas.

```
var url = "https://www.dominio.mx/productos/mi-producto-principal?gclid=Cj0KCQjws-OEBhCkARIsAPhOkIZr1sP9XkD";
var expr1 = /^https:\/\/www.dominio.mx\/productos(?:\/\S+)*\/([^\/]+)$/
var strProducto = (expr1.test(url) ? RegExp.$1 : "indefinido").replace(/-/g,' ');
```

con esto espero tener el siguiente resultado

```
mi producto principal
```

pero obtengo esto

```
mi producto principal?gclid=Cj0KCQjws-OEBhCkARIsAPhOkIZr1sP9XkD
mi producto principal?fbclid=IwAR3I-NG1Pd5DxZhMbjXcrpVplW5OwwmrFGzZRuNgYRbIJy4PiCXuL
mi producto principal?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=spring_sale
```

No he podido resolver esta parte, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: aqui puedes ver una respuesta en ingles de lo que deseas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: Gracias a todos, lo resolví partiendo la cadena final y quedándome con el primer elemento del arreglo

var url = "https://www.dominio.mx/productos/mi-producto-principal?gclid=Cj0KCQjws-OEBhCkARIsAPhOkIZr1sP9XkD";
var expr1 = /^https:\/\/www.dominio.mx\/productos(?:\/\S+)*\/([^\/]+)$/
var strProducto = (expr1.test(url) ? RegExp.$1 : "indefinido").replace(/-/g,' ');
var productParts = strProducto.split('?');
var producto = productParts[0];

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es quedarte con la parte de la URL entre `https://www.dominio.mx/productos/` y los parámetros que empiezan con el caracter `?` puedes utilizar la expresión:

```
var expr1 = /^https:\/\/www.dominio.mx\/productos\/([^?]+).*$/
```

Básicamente lo que hace `([^?]+)` es buscar a partir del final de `/productos/` todos los caracteres que no sean `?`, siendo este el final del grupo que estás buscando.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Créditos: [respuesta a "How can I delete a query string parameter in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634841/12511801)

---

Una opción puede ser:

- Usar la función `removeURLParameter` y obtener el nombre del producto.

Este es el código:

```js
/*
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634841/12511801
*/
function removeURLParameter(url, parameter) {
    //prefer to use l.search if you have a location/link object
    var urlparts = url.split('?');   
    if (urlparts.length >= 2) {

        var prefix = encodeURIComponent(parameter) + '=';
        var pars = urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

        //reverse iteration as may be destructive
        for (var i = pars.length; i-- > 0;) {    
            //idiom for string.startsWith
            if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) {  
                pars.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        return urlparts[0] + (pars.length > 0 ? '?' + pars.join('&') : '');
    }
    return url;
}

// Esta es la URL: 
var url = "https://www.dominio.mx/productos/mi-producto-principal?gclid=Cj0KCQjws-OEBhCkARIsAPhOkIZr1sP9XkD";

// Obtener el resultado en variable separada: 
var resultado = removeURLParameter(url, "gclid");
console.log("URL obtenida: " + resultado);

// Dividir el string obtenido anteriomente - usando el caracter '/': 
var split_resultado = resultado.split('/');

// Aquí se revisa si la URL posee más elementos - para este caso, obtener el nombre del producto
// "está ubicado al final de la URL obtenida en el paso anterior": 
console.log(resultado.indexOf('/') > 0 ? resultado.split('/')[split_resultado.length - 1] : resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizá te sea más cómodo usar la clase [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), que está pensada especialmente para estas tareas:

```js
let url = "https://www.dominio.mx/productos/mi-producto-principal?gclid=Cj0KCQjws-OEBhCkARIsAPhOkIZr1sP9XkD";
let urlObj = new URL(url);

console.log('Base:', urlObj.origin)
console.log('Path:', urlObj.pathname)
console.log('Parámetros',urlObj.search)
```

La única pega es que no está soportada por Internet Explorer, pero cualquier navegador con menos de 7 años no debería darte problemas